# umbraco contour check if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, umbraco, contour

I am working in Umbraco 4.7 and using contour 1.6 to create forms. I cannot upgrade because our site is hosted elsewhere.  I need some help with some code while they migrate our site back to our servers.  I have a check box I would like to 1. check if it is checked and if it is add a link inline.  I have this so far which works, but it works before the page loads and the box is unchecked.  How do I get it to work only when the box has been checked?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {    
      if($(".contourField checkbox paynow checkbox alternating").attr("checked")==true)
{
   window.location = '/paypal';
}
else
{
  window.location = '#'
}
   }   
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, are you saying the box should be checked when the page loads? Or are you wanting to essentially watch the checkbox, and if it becomes checked, then create a link?

If you want to watch the checkbox, you can bind to its 'change' event. Here's a jsfiddle that will help:
http://jsfiddle.net/jeffstagg/gfHKa/

```
$(function() {
    var chkbox = $('#chkbox');
    chkbox.change(function() {
        alert(' is it checked? ' +
              (chkbox.attr('checked')? "yes" : "no")
              );
    });              
});
```

If you're wanting to just check if the box is checked when the page / document is loaded, then you could use something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jeffstagg/C7mzM/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chkbox = $('#chkbox');
    chkbox.attr('checked') ?
        alert("it's checked") :
        alert("it's not checked");
});
```

As for your own code, you're doing a check to see if your checkbox object attr "checked" == true or false.
$(object).attr('checked') returns either "checked" if it is checked, or undefined if it is not checked, rather than true or false.